# Transmit same data to different ports using Role-Links in Biztalk

Tags: wcf, biztalk, role

I have three servers which are assigned different IDs

Server1 = ID1

Server2 = ID2

Server3 = ID3

I want to get data for Server1 from Server2 and Server3, I have to send **same ID (ID1)** to the other two servers to fetch data. I want to achieve this by using Role-Link (because in future there could be more different servers), Issue is I can't give similar Destination Party Values to the Party Identifiers. How can I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Actually in Role Links you can't define two different parties with same identifiers. I handle this by using multiple Receive Locations using Schedule Adapter which generates same SourceServerID and different DestinationServerIDs. It is working like a charm now.